# Nutch - deleting segments

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I have a Nutch crawl with 4 segments which are fully indexed using the `bin/nutch solrindex` command. Now I'm all out of storage on the box, so can I delete the 4 segments and retain only the crawldb and continue crawling from where I left it?

Since all the segments are merged and indexed to Solr I don't see a problem in deleting the segments, or am I wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help on the Nutch mailing list, I found out that I can delete those segments.