# Nutch segments disk space requirements grow fast

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am running a Nutch(1.16)/Solr(8.5.1) crawling indexing system. I am using roughly 26000 URLs as seedlist and have so far indexed ~1 Million pages with `./bin/crawl -i -s ./urls data 500`. This morning the segments folder has grown to 120GB which seems a lot for a million pages. I read [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/HardwareRequirements) 1TB per 100 Million pages is a rough space guidance so I am running at 10 times that for segments alone. I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422174/nutch-deleting-segments) that I can delete the segments, if they have been merged into Solr and only need linkdb and crawldb in the long run. But sadly the conversation leading to that conclusion is missing.

I deleted the segments folder and started the process again to get clean numbers without leftovers from testruns. After adding another 250.000 pages to the Solr index the segments folder has grown again to 40GB.

So my questions:

1. Can I generally delete segments files when an iteration was merged into Solr
2. Why are they not deleted automatically. As things stand, I would need to empty that folder every few days.
3. Is there some way to prevent the segments from growing so fast or better some setting that automatically deletes segments after indexing in Solr.
4. Does it seem like I am doing something fundamentally wrong for my segments to grow so big so quickly.

I can provide config files if necessary but I am running with pretty much vanilla config. I upped the fetcher threads to 25 and the available RAM to 24GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Can I generally delete segments files when an iteration was merged into Solr

Yes, if you don't want to use the segment for other purposes.

> 2. Why are they not deleted automatically.

`bin/crawl` is a shell script easy to adapt at your needs, just add a the command `rm -rf "$CRAWL_PATH"/segments/$SEGMENT` to the loop. But you could also delete segments from yesterday (segment names are timestamps). Sometimes, if there is an issue, you need to inspect the segment to figure out what went wrong.

> 3. Is there some way to prevent the segments from growing so fast

If you do not need the raw content of the crawled pages (HTML but also PDF etc.), it's possible to parse the documents in the fetcher step. That's usually faster and saves space in the segment because only the parsed text and metadata is stored. This is configured by:

- setting the property `fetcher.parse` to true,
- `fetcher.store.content` to false and
- removing (comment out) the parse step in the script `bin/crawl` and

Apache Nutch is more a toolbox to build a crawler, so there's no single way to use it. But bug reports and suggestions are always welcome.